# EGL native library crash on Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge on Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, egl, android-firmware

Recently I've got all users of Samsung Galaxy S7 complaining that app crashes instantly upon start. I didn't get any crash logs from Crashlytics about this issue which was strange at least. But luckily some users reported the issues to Play Store and I was able to get at least some info.

So here's the log from Play Store dev console:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/hero2ltexx/hero2lte:6.0.1/MMB29K/G935FXXU1APF2:user/release-keys'
Revision: '9'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 18857, tid: 18900, name: GLThread 12749  >>> com.some.package <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x6b260
    x0   0000007fb17836c0  x1   0000007fb1783788  x2   0000000000000001  x3   0000000000000001
    x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000007f981afe50  x6   0000000000000000  x7   0000000000000000
    x8   0000000000000001  x9   0000007f9993a570  x10  0000000000000001  x11  0000000000000036
    x12  0000000000000001  x13  0000000000000000  x14  0000007f9a8ed000  x15  0000000000000000
    x16  0000007fa50afa40  x17  0000000000000000  x18  0000000000570000  x19  0000000000000000
    x20  000000000006b000  x21  0000000000000000  x22  0000007f981791c0  x23  0000000000000000
    x24  0000007fb17836c0  x25  0000007f9a8dc000  x26  0000007f981afd60  x27  0000000000000001
    x28  0000000000000000  x29  0000007f99939db0  x30  0000007fa3d50d74
    sp   0000007f99939d10  pc   0000007fa3d50bfc  pstate 0000000060000000

backtrace:
    #00 pc 0000000000645bfc  /system/vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so (eglp_swap_buffers+248)
    #01 pc 000000000002cf6c  /system/lib64/libEGL.so (eglSwapBuffersWithDamageKHR+560)
    #02 pc 000000000009a5b8  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so
    #03 pc 0000000003f17ad4  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 0x2f34000)
```

This makes me think that the issue is a firmware problem because:

- occurs only on S7 Edge (although once it happenned on plain S7)
- last 4 lines of the stack trace point on EGL system libs

So my questions would be:

- Is it possible to find out which part of app code makes calls that trigger the issue?
- Has anybody got the same/similar issue and fixed it?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: In Android 6.0 update for S7 Samsung added floating-point render targets. So I'd suggest double check initialization code of framebuffers and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

try set final modify with data render

```
final FloatBuffer tmpfbXYZ = actor.fbXYZ
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0, tmpfbXYZ);
```